# Error when using rasterio.mask to mask a raster using a shapefile

Tags: mask, shapefile, rasterio

I am trying to mask a raster with a shape file (AOI, area of interest). The area of the AOI is larger than the raster area.

```
with fiona.open("..\GIS\AOI_meters.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open(fp2) as src:
     out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, filled=True, nodata=0)
     out_meta = src.meta
```

I get this errorMessage:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Affine'
```

I don´t understand why I get this error message. I tested src.transform and the Affine matrix looks fine.